# Abstract environment: interaction between hyperref and acronyms in ettauth.cls

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, acronyms, abstract

I am submitting a paper for a journal that uses class `ettauth.cls`. Inside `abstract` I use some acronyms with the help of `acronym` package. I also load `hyperref` package for the cross-referencing. With that I noticed that `latex` issues the message:

`LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.`

Even in the end of last run.

The `abstract` is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\absize}{\fontsize{11.5pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
 \def\volumeyear{0000}
 \gdef\copyrightline{Copyright \copyright\ \volumeyear\ John Wiley \& Sons, Ltd.}
 \newbox\absbox
 \def\abstract{\lrbox\absbox\minipage{\textwidth}%
  \normalfont%
  {\noindent\sffamily\bfseries\absize{ABSTRACT}}\par\vspace{10pt}\normalsize%
  }
\def\endabstract{\copyrightline\endminipage\endlrbox}
```

And the MWE:

```
\documentclass{ettauth}

\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{SDR}{Software Defined Radio}
\end{acronym}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}

\begin{abstract}
\ac{SDR}
\end{abstract}
\maketitle


\section{Intro}

\end{document}
```

The class `ettauth.cls`, maybe downloaded at: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)2161-3915/homepage/ettauth.cls

I think something is missing at the end of `abstract` definition, as this doesn't happen when I use, e.g., `IEEEtran`.

Comment: This appears independently of `hyperref` and should be regarded as a bug in `acronym`, I believe. With `acro` it doesn't happen.

Comment: I don't know if it can be attributed to `acronym` because as I said it worked with `IEEEtran`.

Comment: I tried with `glossaries` and also the problem doesn't appear.

Comment: The difference between `ettauth` and `IEEEtran` can be explained in how the abstract is managed.

Answer (score 2):

I can propose a hack; after all, you don't want to mark as used an acronym appearing in the abstract, so it should be expanded the first time you use it in text.

```
\documentclass{ettauth}

\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\absac}[1]{\acl{#1} (\acs{#1})}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\abstract\expandafter{\abstract\let\ac\absac}    

\newacro{SDR}{Software Defined Radio}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}

\begin{abstract}
\ac{SDR} and something else.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{Intro}

\ac{SDR} and something else about \ac{SDR}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your hack works. So the problem is in the expansion of `\ac`? Before your answer I was wondering to use the `acro` package instead.

Comment: @cacamailg I couldn't track the source of the problem. Using `acro` is good, but maybe the journal hasn't an updated TeX distribution. Contact the persons in charge for information about the packages you're allowed to use.

Comment: Actually I tried your hack with the real document, but it didn't work, while in the example above it works. Very strange. Since I need to provide the PDF for review, I will convert my acronyms to be used with `acro` package instead.